# Object Positioning is not updating in Rendered View

Tags: modeling, rendering, animation

My object is properly aligned in the solid viewport so it does not collide with my floor but in my rendered view it is different. Half of my objects are colliding with the floor

[image]

Comment: since you didn't provide useful information - please provide blend file so we can check it out

Answer (score 1):

It should be a displacement in material nodes.

Remove texture from displacement socket

[image]

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but can't be sure without having a look at the file.